# Event with probability of 33%, reduced in probability by 18%

Tags: probability

There is a three-sided die (sides A, B, and C) that is evenly weighted. The chances of rolling 'A' are 33%.

Perhaps you want to cheat, so you look online for modifications. You see one modification that advertises "This one simple trick can reduce the probability of rolling 'A' by 18%!".

1. What is the principle at play here? Is there a name for this concept? What concepts do I need to familiarize myself with to understand the nature of this problem? What would I look for in the index of a good math textbook on probability?
2. What does it mean, in mathematical terms, to *reduce the probability* of an event that has a well-defined probability? Is this a sum? A product of some kind? Is there a well-known formula?
3. What are the steps to solving this problem?

Comment: Are you referring to a technique to throw the die? I think that it is reasonable that using a specific technique to throw the die can alter probabilities, for example if you throw it vertically then the face up will take place almost 100% of the times

Comment: "Modification"? What kind of a die roll is this?

Comment: @Tortar This would be physical modification to the dice that changes the probability of each number occurring.

For clarity, I am trying to understand and model (with dice) a situation that often confuses me:
Say there is a 33% chance I will get cancer. But a study says I can reduce my chances of getting cancer by 18% if I eat only fruit for the rest of my life. If I only eat fruit for the rest of my life, what are my chances of getting cancer?

Comment: For the cancer example, suppose the world consisted only of 100 people, and 40 of them will get cancer eventually, so you might say "there is a 40% chance you will get cancer." However, maybe 5 of these people only eat fruit, and only 1 of these 5 people get cancer. So you might say "people that only eat fruit have a 20% chance of getting cancer." Note that these "chances of getting cancer" are not really true probabilities, nor is the link between eating fruit and getting cancer implied to be causal; they are just empirical reflections of the population. (cont'd)

Comment: The restriction to only-fruit-eaters can be viewed as "conditioning" in probabilistic terms; you are essentially using the extra information "I only eat fruit" to restrict to a smaller population of people. (cont'd)

Comment: I don't think this idea (which comes from looking at complicated interactions of different covariates in an actual population of people) applies to a die-throwing situation with physical modifications. But maybe a silly example could be a 6-sided die with 2 As, 2 Bs, and 2 Cs, but one of the As is colored blue while the other 5 sides are red. Then by conditioning on the event "I rolled a red side," the conditional probability of rolling A becomes "reduced" to $1/5$ instead of $1/3$. Not sure if this is what you are looking for.